# Windows defender detecting exe as Trojan:Win32/Azden.A!cl virus

Tags: .net, trojan, windows-defender

I'm facing an issue while installing an application on windows 10 enterprise edition. After installing application windows defender detect it as virus (Trojan:Win32/Azden.A!cl) and delete it's exe from installed location which is Program Files (x86)\Application Folder, this hasn't been observed in windows 7 and previously everything was running fine. I made this application myself and used VB.Net and Framework 3.5 to build this.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You might have encountered a false positive. Microsoft has a procedure for removing those from their signatures.

Please submit your application to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/antimalware-support/developer-resources

The procedure works as follows:

> Submit the file in question as a software developer. Wait until your submission has a final determination.
>
> If you’re not satisfied with our determination of the submission, use the developer contact form provided with the submission results to reach Microsoft. We will use the information you provide to investigate further if necessary.
>
> We encourage all software vendors and developers to read about how Microsoft identifies malware and unwanted software. 
>   [Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/antimalware-support/file-submission-guide)

Comment: I wrote a short (25 lines) C++ console app, and compiled it with VS2019 16.2.3 on Window 10 with all updates. When executing it, it stops and pops up "Virus & threat protection" window. Process stops, and the exe file disappears. In Windows Defender it shows: Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml  Alert level: Severe  Status:Quarantined. I'm going to report this issue to MS.

Btw, the C++ program just calculates a permutation, divides it by some cube, and cout prints result.